# How to trigger an update for UDF

Tags: excel, vba, colors, user-defined-functions, conditional-formatting

I found code to generate a number associated to color cells to use for conditionals

UDFs apparently do not update themselves automatically after changing the cell value, this seems to be a problem with conditionals on color cells.

How can I tweak this code so once I change the color of a cell, the macro will automatically update the associated number?

```vb
Public Function ColorIndex(CellColor As Range)
    ColorIndex = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

**Example spreadsheet**:
Upon switching column 'H' from green to white, the associated number in column 'I' should change from 35 to -4142.

[image: Example spreadsheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the cell's color doesn't fire the change event in the worksheet.

But if you change at least one cell (for example typing something) after color changes, the UDF could be executed by adding Application.Volatile to force the update.

```
Function My_Func() 
 Application.Volatile 
 ' 
 ' Remainder of the function 
 ' 
End Function
```

As per the documentation:

> Marks a user-defined function as volatile. A volatile function must be
> recalculated whenever calculation occurs in any cells on the
> worksheet. A nonvolatile function is recalculated only when the input
> variables change. This method has no effect if it's not inside a
> user-defined function used to calculate a worksheet cell.

In your code:

```
Public Function ColorIndex(CellColor As Range)
 Application.Volatile 
 ColorIndex = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

Comment: Hi @Ricardo Diaz thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, it didn't work... could it be because it says: "whenever calculation occurs" and in my case no calculation is performed only a color change? Let me know!

Comment: @Matteo Note that is a very bad idea to use colors to transport information. Formatting such as color should **only** be used to make specific information *visible* that is already present in the data but never to transport data/information! Why? Excel is very slow in working with formatting, formulas cannot access formatting and there is no events for formatting only for values.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Noted, thanks I understand your point, it's fair. However, the dataset was made available as an Excel spreadsheet, and on top of my head I didn't think about a better way to classify/categorized information. Any advice is welcome though!

Comment: My advice is fix it. Write a little code that turns your colored information into an extra column of real data. And from then on use your data column instead of coloring and put conditional formatting on that data column to see your data green/white. My advice is don't continue with your bad approach. Example: add an extra column and use `g` and `w` for green and white to mark your rows and conditional formatting for better visibility. Even better, use more significant words than `g` and `w` to make it meaningful.

Comment: If you cannot fix it because of reasons you have, then the only way is to write a code that loops through your rows and turn color into data and run it with a button (would be the same code as for the suggestion in above comment) but you need to run that code manually each time you want to syncronize color and data, because Excel has no event to run it automatically on color change.

Comment: I see I was looking into some suggestions and all seemed to have mixed answers, so I just wanted to make sure what was right and what wasn't. I appreciate the help, tanks again.